# Download OpenCL AMD APP SDK 3.0 for windows and linux

Tags: opencl, pyopencl, amd-app

I want to download standalone version of OpenCL AMD APP SDK 3.0 for Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

AMD has remove the files from their servers.
There is a copy in the internet here:

For [Windows](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/SDK-DDK/ATI-Stream-SDK.shtml)
For [Linux](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nicehashsgminerv5viptools/files/APP%20SDK%20A%20Complete%20Development%20Platform/)

Comment: Sounds abit fake for me. Also there no need anymore for those SDK btw.

Comment: It not fake. you can try it yourself. and until amd will find a decent solution for their gpu. (rocom is only on Linux and only latest gpu, and it beta. so ... most of the amd users want to do deep learning still needs the sdk)

Comment: APPSDK has been discontinued. OpenCL functionality on Linux is via ROCm and on Windows it is still part of Catalyst drivers. OCL headers are available here though: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-ICD-Loader

Comment: @BorisIvanov you need to clarify what you mean by "there is no need anymore for those SDK", as without clarification your comment is completely useless. Please provide an alternative SDK and where to find it

Comment: @iedoc: According to : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_APP_SDK:
AMD APP SDK was available for 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Microsoft Windows and Linux but was removed from AMD's official website.[3] A developer stated in a forum post that the SDK was discontinued as the required libraries are now included with the drivers.

Comment: thank you for explaining @BorisIvanov! I appreciate that!

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use OCL SDK instead 
https://gpuopen.com/compute-product/opencl-sdk/
https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/OCL-SDK/releases

Comment: This is possible if you have newer GPUs, but not for some older cards/systems.